# How can I receive an array through jQuery to pre-check checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, cakephp, checkbox

I have a list of 'trades' like plumbing/carpentry/etc which display on a page with checkboxes for each (each checkbox has an ID that matches its 'trade id')

I have an array which contains the trades that need to be 'PRE checked' for example:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Trade] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Trade] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
            )

    )

)
```

So on the page I need the checkboxes with ID's of 1 and 2 to be 'pre checked'.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Try JSON. It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: What variable is that array stored in?

Comment: $preselects would contain that array in this case.

Comment: Well, to narrow things down let me try and re-iterate: I need each [Trade][id] compared to the inputs id

Comment: Managed to get it going, I'll post my results here in an hour or so.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the .html() method when looping through the array of id's.

```
$(".IDs").each(function(){
  if($(this).val()==[whatever value]){
    $("#div").html('<input type="checkbox" checked>value</input>');
  } else {
    $("#div").html('<input type="checkbox">value</input>');
  }
});
```